# Returning object with key value pairs based on arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that loops over key/value pairs in an object and that returns an object with the same keys, but each value has now become a function. I want to make sure that typescript correctly grasps the returned object for autocomplete. This works in de following silly function:

```
interface Args {
  [layer: string]: Boolean
}

function sillyFunction<T extends Args>(layers: T): T {
  return layers
}

sillyFunction({ layerName: true }).layerName // this works
```

But now I have the following code, where the layers object (key/boolean pairs) is used to create a new returnObject with key/function pairs.:

```
interface Args {
  [layer: string]: Boolean
}

interface ReturnedObject {
  [layer: string]: Function
}

function createFunctions<T extends Args>(layers: T): T {
  let returnObj = {} as ReturnedObject;

  for (let layer in layers) {
    returnObj[layer] = (label) => `${layer} ${label}`
  }

  return returnObj;
}

createFunctions({ layerName: true }).layerName // doesnt work
```

This obviously gives me the error 'ReturnedObject' is not assignable to type T. How can I make sure that typescript 'understands' that the keys inside the object are still the same, but values have become functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a mapped type to transform `T` to a new type with a the same properties, but a different type for each property. The predefined type `Record` will work well in this case, since all the keys will have the same type. Also I would be more specific then `Function` about the type of the function, `Function` is the `any` of function signatures, it allows invocation with any parameter

```
interface Args {
  [layer: string]: boolean
}

type ReturnedObject<T> =  Record<keyof T, (label: string) => string>

function createFunctions<T extends Args>(layers: T): ReturnedObject<T> {
  let returnObj = {} as ReturnedObject<T>;

  for (let layer in layers) {
    returnObj[layer] = (label) => `${layer} ${label}`
  }

  return returnObj;
}

var l = createFunctions({ layerName: true })
l.layerName("")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYGdkG8CwAUMsgNoA2cAntAFzJZhSgYC69ARgPZfkRwgiAXyJEwVAA4oAShDABXKCAgATAPIcAVhARgAPABUAfMgC8JWQi5QVegNYQqXGMgMAaZAApKHCOXqMzCAYAJRmJoEsRqKEMPIgusBcIMgIUPyQAGLxiclYhsgQAB6QICo46NhG3tTQWPQGIfSyCkqqGtq6hiYExMh8YMjprSAdZnhCyHA4LYrK6lo6+sYA3DEkMNZeA-21UMiguzRQWGG9JCTDcx0Ue6zjNb7kYaYmAAYAJLiUx5NfPn4hG8iCQRIQQUM5HNISMOmtCGCiAA3OD7cjjNIZCDZBJgJIgLCeXBHaAAOTgAFsIPQmPIUEIQkRyAA6H5kykQTwAIi5YQA9HzkEA)

Answer (score -1):

your "createFunctions" return type is T but you expected to be ReturnedObject.

just define return type as ReturnedObject

```
function createFunctions<T extends Args>(layers: T): ReturnedObject
```

and it should work

Comment: Yeah, but then you lose type safety. The OP wanted for keys of ReturnedObject to be the same as T.

Comment: That will remove the error, but will not actually preserve the keys of `T`, the return type would allow any key to be accessed since it has an index signature